# How to manage page_views in different languages and with custom URL parameters?

Tags: next.js, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a nextjs app with firebase-analytics.

I'm using some dynamic routes, for example `/object/{OBJECT_ID}/details`

In ga4, in the `Pages and screens` section, if I filter by `Page path`, I get a bunch of different paths that are supposed to be grouped together

```
/object/abc-123/details
/object/def-456/details
/object/ghi-789/details
```

If I filter by `Page title`, the pages are still not grouped together because my page titles are translated

```
Details
Détails
Detalles
```

I'm using the [Automatically track screens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#automatically_track_screens) feature of firebase-analytics.

I'm considering 3 different solutions:

1. Disable automatic screen tracking and manually trigger events using nextjs router

   - The doc does not mention how to disable screen tracking on the web.
     I tried to initialize analytics using the following, but I still see `page_view` events in DebugView:

   ```js
   import { initializeAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
   import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

   const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

   const analytics = initializeAnalytics(app, {
     config: {
       send_page_view: false,
     },
   });
   ```

   - I'm not sure of the proper way to manually trigger events using nextjs router
2. Find a way to group the related pages in ga4 so that it ignores my URL parameters
3. Find a way to link together the pages that have translated titles

Is any of this possible? I feel like this should be a fairly common usecase, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: Page titles are going to be browser dependent. If the user is having their screens translated, it will capture that and cause your data to be ungrouped. This was the same for older versions of Google Analytics as well. For the `page_path`, if you are placing an object ID into the URL, and it is different, isn't it expected it would be ungrouped? You are sending the signal to GA that these are indeed different pages because the URLs don't match.

Comment: @A_Patterson The thing is, most of my paths start with the id of the object being worked on. I want to know how much time my users spend on each page, but I don't care if they are on the `Details` page on 2 different objects. Kind of like on GitHub you have the path `{REPO_NAME}/issues`, `{REPO_NAME}`/pulls`, I would want to know how many users view the `issues` page without having to sum every existing repo

Comment: So you are more interested in the `/object/{OBJECT_ID}` path rather than the `/details` directories? I think you might be able to leave it as it and use Looker Studio, create a new parameter based off the `page_path` and split it on `/` before details with `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` function. That way you don't have to alter your capture or how your URLs are structured.